# Windows Powershell Parentheses in Folder Names

Tags: powershell

Powershell n00b here. I want to mount an iso using PowerShell. I successfully did it like this:

```
PS C:\> PowerShell Mount-DiskImage C:\3D_Ultra_Pinball_Thrillride\pinball-disc.iso


Attached          : True
BlockSize         : 0
DevicePath        : \\.\CDROM2
FileSize          : 214403072
ImagePath         : C:\3D_Ultra_Pinball_Thrillride\pinball-disc.iso
LogicalSectorSize : 2048
Number            : 2
Size              : 214403072
StorageType       : 1
PSComputerName    :
```

But now I want to do one that has parentheses in the filename, like this:

```
PS C:\> PowerShell Mount-DiskImage "C:\Program Files (x86)\Warcraft III\warcraft-disc.iso"
x86 : The term 'x86' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:35
+ Mount-DiskImage C:\Program Files (x86)\Warcraft III\warcraft-disc.iso
+                                   ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (x86:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How do I escape the parentheses? Backticks don't seem to work, nor does quoting the path with single or double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes make it a string literal and should work fine. Why are you calling powershell while in the powershell prompt? Perhaps that is the issue.

```
PS C:\> Mount-DiskImage 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\SLI_3.0.0_A00 (1).iso'


Attached          : True
BlockSize         : 0
DevicePath        : \\.\CDROM1
FileSize          : 1882193920
ImagePath         : C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\SLI_3.0.0_A00 (1).iso
LogicalSectorSize : 2048
Number            : 1
Size              : 1882193920
StorageType       : 1
PSComputerName    :
```

Comment: Not calling PowerShell from within PowerShell did the trick, thanks. I didn't even realize that's what was happening.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the parentheses:

```
Mount-DiskImage "C:\Program Files `(x86`)\Common Files\SLI_3.0.0_A00 `(1`).iso"
```

Backtick (`) is the escape character in PowerShell.